Asymptotic behavior and of an integral on a d-dimensional torus
I am trying to evaluate the asymptotic behavior of the following integral as $t \to \infty$:
$$
I(t; \mathbf{v}) = \int_{[-\pi, \pi]^d} \frac{\sin(t f(\mathbf{k}))}{\sin(f(\mathbf{k}))} e^{i t \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{v}} \, d\mathbf{k}
$$
where $\mathbf{v}$ is a $d$-dimensional constant vector and
$$
f(\mathbf{k}) = \arcsin\left(\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{1}{d} \sum_{j=1}^d \cos(k_j)\right)^2}\right).
$$
Key points and progress
I think the factor $\frac{\sin(t f(\mathbf{k}))}{\sin(f(\mathbf{k}))}$ becomes a kind of $\delta$ function as $t \to \infty$.
However I am not sure how to handle it.
Question
How can I rigorously evaluate the asymptotic behavior of the integral $ I(t; \mathbf{v}) $ as $ t \to \infty $?
How can I evaluate the convergence rate with respect to $t$?

have you tried the method of stationary phase/Laplace's method?

@LSpice Thank you. I have corrected it.

@nervxxx Thank you. I have tried the method of stationary phase. In this case, the phase function does not have zero of its gradient. Therefore I thought the method does not work for Fourier transform. Isn’t it?

The dominant contributions for large $t$ come from the two regions around $\mathbf k_0 = \{0,\ldots,0\}$ and $\mathbf k_\pi = \{\pi,\ldots,\pi\}$, where $f(\mathbf k)\ll 1$. Note that $f(\mathbf k_0)=f(\mathbf k_\pi)=0$ are the only zeroes of $f$ in the integration interval.
$
\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}
$
We first focus on the region around $\mathbf k_0$. Substituting $\mathbf k \mapsto \mathbf q/t$ and expanding the integrand around $t=\infty$ we find
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(t f(\mathbf q/t))}{t\sin(f(\mathbf q/t))} = \sinc\left(\frac{|\mathbf q|}{\sqrt d}\right) + \mathcal O(t^{-2}) ,
\end{align}
with the cardinal sine,
$$ \sinc(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}.$$
For the one-dimensional case $d=1$ this gives
\begin{align}
I^{(d=1)}_{0}(\infty;v)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dq \sinc(q) \, e^{i q v} \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}[\sign(1-v)+\sign(1+v)],
\end{align}
which is the well known Fourier transform of $\sinc(q)$.
The region around $\mathbf k_\pi$ contributes the same, but with an additional phase factor, such that in total
\begin{align}
I^{(d=1)}(\infty;v)&=\frac{\pi}{2}[\sign(1-v)+\sign(1+v)][1+\cos(\pi v)].
\end{align}
In higher dimensions the calculation is quite similar,
\begin{align}
I^{(d)}_{0}(\infty;\mathbf v)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^d \mathbf q \sinc\left(\frac{|\mathbf q|}{\sqrt d}\right) \, e^{i \mathbf q \cdot \mathbf  v},
\end{align}
which now is the $d$-dimensional Fourier transform of the cardinal sine, with argument $|\mathbf q|/\sqrt{d}$. In $d=2$, Mathematica can evaluate this transform, with result
\begin{align}
I^{(d=2)}_{0}(\infty;\mathbf v)&= \Re\left(\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{1-2 |\mathbf v|^2}}\right).
\end{align}
The region around $\mathbf k_\pi$ should again contribute a phase shift. Note that the result for $I^{(d)}_{0}(\infty;\mathbf v)$ must be a function of $|\mathbf v|$, as the Fourier transform of an isotropic function is isotropic, see the update below. Maybe it can be generalized to general $d$, the op should check the literature. I must go to bed now...
Update #1
See, e.g., MO:315613 and references therein for a discussion of the case $d>2$.
In $d=3$, the solution seems to be (maybe up to a constant)
\begin{align}
I^{(d=3)}_{0}(\infty;\mathbf v)&=
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\delta(1-\sqrt3|\mathbf{v}|)}{\sqrt3|\mathbf{v}|}.
\end{align}

Thank you for your rapid reply. I am trying to verify the calculations for the multi-dimensional case. One thing I want to know is the order of convergence of
$I(t;\mathbf{v})$ with respect to
$$. Is it easy? I cannot obtain this by the method of stationary phase.

@KoHey See new first equation (for the convergence), and my update #1.

Thank you for your update. I have calculated them for d dimensional cases.
I want to evaluate the convergence rate with respect to $t$ which may depends on $d$. How can we evaluate them.

I calculated them but I found that the factor $\frac{1}{t^{d-1}}$ may be missed through variable transform. @fred
